# Difficulty layout out my basic application using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm relatively new to Java and I've spent the past two evenings trying to get my Java program layed out correctly and I'm hoping someone could clear a few things up for me.

The layout was all going well until I decided to add a menu bar to my application using JMenuBar, and now for some reason my application's menu bar either vanishes, attaches to the top centre of the pane the width of the File menu bar, or works perfectly but hides the buttons below it.

My more recent try has me a little closer, but for some reason the height of the menu bar now seems to be massive when I set the menu bar container to BorderLayout.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong?

```
JPanel mainPane = new JPanel();
BoxLayout progLayout = new BoxLayout(mainPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

mainPane.setLayout(progLayout);
setContentPane(mainPane);

JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
menuBar.add(file);

JMenuItem project = new JMenuItem("New Project");
JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
file.add(project);
file.add(exit);

JPanel row0 = new JPanel();
BorderLayout menuBarLayout = new BorderLayout();
row0.setLayout(menuBarLayout);
row0.add(menuBar);
add(row0);


JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
row1.setOpaque(false);
row1.add(domainLabel);
row1.add(projectNameInput);
row1.add(userSubmit);
row1.add(userClear);
add(row1);
```

Many thanks.

*Edit: I finally managed to get it working thanks to the below answer. See comments below to the solution.

Comment: Usually I've added the JMenuBar to the JFrame itself via its `setJMenuBar(...)` method. This will add it in a BorderLayout.NORTH fashion to just above the contentPane. If my JFrame is created elsewhere, I sometimes give classes above a public `getJMenuBar()` method to allow other classes to extract the menu bar created here.

Comment: First of all this is so inappropriate :) "File.add(exit);" in java variable should start with lower case and any other word joint by camel case. LOL I thought I never saw static method such as .add() in File class... :( bad practise

Comment: @Brogrammer Thanks for pointing that out. As you can probably tell by the rest of the code, I do follow the naming convention you mentioned, I must have typed the uppercase without thinking about it. This has now been edited to stop anyone else getting confused ;)

Comment: +2, for responding... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reiterate: Usually I've added the JMenuBar to the JFrame itself via its `setJMenuBar(...)` method. This will add it in a `BorderLayout.NORTH` fashion to just above the contentPane. If my JFrame is created elsewhere, I sometimes give classes above a public `getJMenuBar()` method to allow other classes to extract the menu bar created here.

If I absolutely need to add the JMenuBar to a JPanel, I give that JPanel a BorderLayout and add the JMenuBar to the `BorderLayout.NORTH` position. If I need other components added via a BoxLayout, then I add a BoxLayout-using JPanel to the main JPanel's `BorderLayout.CENTER` position and add the other sub-components to the BoxLayout-using JPanel.

Tutorials include:
[Using Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)
[Using Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: In addition : There is nice tutorial on this website, which can guide you through...http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/menu-bar-java.shtml

Comment: @Brogrammer: thanks for the info. I just have to say that I'm reluctant to recommend roseindia sites since I've seen many recommendations there that were just plain wrong. I prefer to recommend the standard Oracle Swing tutorials as linked to in my answer above.

Comment: Oops...I should beware than too! Thanks, well another resource is : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html but bit complicated... :) Hopefully OP will check this oracle link

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thank you for the recommendation on the setJMenuBar() method, I will look into this now.

Comment: Finally got it working, thank you.

I used the setJMenyBar() method as recommended (thanks for this, I didn't know it existed) and then set the main JFrame to BorderLayout and set the JPanels to North and Center.

Comment: @BigJoe: actually the JFrame is BorderLayout by default. Check out the layout tutorials for all the details.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels So it is! I never had a chance to read through all of the tutorial last night. Thank you making me aware of that.